# Access Post Content with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I've created a `lightbox` function which loads over the top when a user clicks on a post link in the archive. The overlay needs to display images and short paragraphs of text in a slideshow style (with next and prev buttons), those fields are created with as `Advanced Custom Fields` flexible repeater.

I'm using `JS` to `.append()` a div to the body and I need to then query the post, by `ID` I guess, within my js to fetch the first value from that `ACF` repeater, then second, then third and so on, when the next/prev buttons are hit. I'm thinking that I could perhaps quickly grab an array of those values when the lightbox is loaded and then cycle through them, but am not sure where to start.

What I don't want to do is simply `.load()` the post, headers and all, into the lightbox, just the images (and short peices of text) one at a time.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we're missing some crucial information here. What platform are you using? Where are the posts saved? What kind of posts? How does the lightbox load this information?

Comment: Sorry @Polyducks, I thought I'd posted this on WordPress Stack Exchange and so the context was clear... this is a WordPress related question so I'd be accessing WordPress posts in the MySQL database.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with an answer. I've retagged it as Wordpress for future searchers. Glad I could uh... sort of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got around this issue by storing the information that I need in an array during the initial loop so that when the user clicks on the post I  `.append()` an overlay to the body and then create a slide for `.each()` of the nodes in that array. The information displayed in each slide is pretty minimal in this case, just an image or a single line of text so this solution works more efficiently than querying the database on each click or lightbox load.